# Failure sending mail in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

Trying to get a very basic program to send me an email. I have 3 text boxes.

TextBox1 is a ReadOnly TextBox with my email in it
TextBox2 is for "Your Email"
TextBox3 is for your message

And there is a Button (Button1) That says "Send"

Here is the code for my entire project. I removed my email and password in this question for security purposes.

When I run the program and type in "Test1234@live.com" in TextBox2 and "TestEmail1234" into TextBox3 and press send, it takes me back to the coding page and says 
"SmtpException was unhandled.
Failure sending mail"

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword")
        'using Gmail
        smtpServer.Port = 587
        smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True

        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("my email@gmail.com", TextBox1.Text)
        mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text
        mail.Body = TextBox3.Text

        smtpServer.Send(mail)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and tell at which line it goes wrong?

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt A what? I'm new to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Right click the beginning line of your Button1_click sub and choose 'Add breakpoint'. Then run the code, and it will stop at your breakpoint. Then in the top menu, u can select DEBUG > step into/over ..., and go through your code line per line. At a certain moment your code will break. Could you provide us the line at which the code breaks? cheers.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt "smtpServer.Send(mail)" is where it pops up with "failure sending mail"

Comment: What is in your textBox1.text?
Because the mail.To.Add() needs to have an email as parameter, and I Doubt this is the case in your example, since you give TextBox1.text as the 'name' for the Mailaddress.

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt in textbox1 it says "kevinwolf228@gmail.com" because thats where i want the message to be sent. i changed the port to 465. because supposedly, thats the new gmail smtp send port.

Comment: One tip. In case anyone needs. Make sure your Body Text length is about more than 7 characters...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems, I'll just give you a working script

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
Dim message As New MailMessage
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
Dim instance As IDisposable


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Mail.Subject = "test email"
    Mail.To.Add("recieveradress@gmail.com")
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("senderadress@gmail.com")
    Mail.Body = "This is an email!"
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("senderaddress@gmail.com", "password")
    SMTP.Port = 587
    SMTP.Send(Mail)
    MsgBox("Sent Successfully")

End Sub
End Class
```